# Add column to R dataframe based on rowname

Tags: r

I have two DFs with a different number of rows which share some of the same **row names**:

```
     DF1                       DF2 
                                   Col
Name1                    Name1      A  
Name3                    Name2      B
Name4                    Name3      C
Name7                    Name4      D 
                         Name5      E
                         Name6      F
                         Name7      G
```

but I would like to make a column in DF1, which has a smaller number of rows from the Col in DF2 based upon matching **row names** shared by both DFs:

```
    DF1                       DF2 
        Col                         Col
Name1    A                Name1      A  
Name3    C                Name2      B
Name4    D                Name3      C
Name7    G                Name4      D 
                          Name5      E
                          Name6      F
                          Name7      G
```

Comment: `library(tidyverse); DF1 %>% left_join(DF2)`?

Comment: Base R, `merge(DF1, DF2, by="Name", all.y=FALSE)`?

Comment: I was unclear, this question is not the same as the inner, outer, left, right question as it deals with the rownames not another column as the "by" variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve what you want

```
DF1 = data.frame(Name = c(1,3,4,7))
DF2 = data.frame(Name = 1:7,Col = letters[1:7])
DF1$Col = DF2$Col[match(DF1$Name,DF2$Name)]
```

Comment: This script works if trying to match using rownames and not columns so it is more helpful in this case:    
            DF1$Col = DF2$Col[match(rownames(DF1),rownames(DF2))]

Comment: great it work for your real data, if so accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

The `tidyverse` way:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(
    Name = c(1, 3, 4, 7))
DF2 <- data.frame(
    Name = seq(1:7),
    Col = LETTERS[1:7]);
DF1 %>% left_join(DF2);
#   Name Col
#1    1   A
#2    3   C
#3    4   D
#4    7   G
```